# Liquibase failing while attempting to drop non-existent TMP_% tables during generateChangeLog

Tags: liquibase

Running

> liquibase generateChangeLog > genChgLog.txt

with the following as my liquibase.properties,

> classpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector
>    J\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar 
>   driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
>   url=jdbc:mysql://{thisisnottheproblem,Iguarantee} 
>   username={it'sright}
>   password={it'sright}
>   referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://{thisisnottheproblem,Iguarantee}
>   referenceUsername={it'sright} 
>   referencePassword={it'sright}
>   changeLogFile=databaseChangeLogSchema.mysql.sql
>   diffTypes=tables,columns,views,primaryKeys,indexes,foreignKeys,sequences,data
>   logLevel=debug

I am consistently getting the likes of this, output to the genChgLog.txt file:

> Starting Liquibase at Wed, 15 May 2019 15:37:32 CDT (version 3.6.3
>   built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48) Unexpected error running Liquibase:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown table
>   'TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU' [Failed SQL: DROP TABLE TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU]
>   liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException:
>   liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown table
>   'TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU' [Failed SQL: DROP TABLE TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU]
>     at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:279)
>     at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1058)
>     at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:199)    at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:137) Caused by:
>   liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown table
>   'TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU' [Failed SQL: DROP TABLE TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU]
>     at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:24)
>     at
>   liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:277)
>     ... 3 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown table
>   'TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU' [Failed SQL: DROP TABLE TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU]
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.java:223)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:66)
>   . . .     at
>   liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:46)
>     at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:19)
>     ... 4 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unknown table
>   'TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU' [Failed SQL: DROP TABLE TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU]
>     at
>   liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:356)
>     at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:57)
>     at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:125)
>     at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:109)
>     at
>   liquibase.database.core.MySQLDatabase.hasBugJdbcConstraintsDeferrable(MySQLDatabase.java:294)
>     at
>   liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(ForeignKeySnapshotGenerator.java:188)
>     ... 25 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'TMP_CTAWHBNCQVQMHSUU'
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782)
>     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666)
>     at
>   liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:352)
>     ... 30 common frames omitted
>
> For more information, please use the --logLevel flag

Each time I run it, it changes the name of the phantom TMP_ tables (although they always begin with TMP_ and then a string of apparently random characters).  I don't know where it's getting these non-existent TMP_ tables from that it wants to drop, but...is there some way to make it only attempt to drop them if they exist?  Of potential note:  it works fine if my only diffType is "tables", "data", or if I have both "tables" and "data" as diffTypes...otherwise, failure...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all the details, but it appears this can happen when using a database user with insufficient permissions. I talked with someone who said that using a root level database user fixed this issue for them.